# 504 Gateway error only on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, internal-server-error, gateway

I am getting a 504 Gateway error when I visit my website through a link in a website. This is only happening on my iPhone though, I am browsing through my website right as we speak with no errors being thrown at me. I also tried inputting the URL through Safari manually but it still gave me the same error.

Has any other users seen this happen before? If so, how were you able to fix it?

If it helps, I am using a cellular data connection.

Comment: have you tried resetting your network settings or connecting to another network?

Comment: @BergQuester, I reset my network settings and still getting a 504 gateway error. I was using a cellular connection so I switched to a nearby wifi connection and that still gave meh the 504 error.

Comment: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html